# Xcode indentation doesn't workn on Enter/Return

Tags: xcode, indentation

I have Xcode 9 on OSX 10.13.

Problem is - Xcode doesn't indent the code when I do:

else + ENTER

The cursor goes to the next line and it positions on the column under the first `e` in `else`.

When I went to the "Xcode -> Preferences -> Text Editing -> Indentation" all settings for `Automatic indent for` are checked, including the `Return` one.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Is there any reason you’re using Xcode9? I believe it is required to use a minimum of Xcode 13 to submit builds to Apple so might be worth updating. You will also be missing out on about 5 years of updates to Swift and iOS by using Xcode 9.

Comment: @Fogmeister, no reason. And I don't care about Swift/iOS. I' using C++... Is Xcode 13 compatible with OSX 10.13? Will indentation be fixed there?

Comment: If you’re writing C++ then you can do much better than Xcode as an IDE. Something like CLion or even Sublime would have much better updates and possibly better support for older versions of MacOS. Xcode 9 is no longer supported by Apple.

Comment: @Fogmeister, CLion uses CMake thingy, which I don't like. Never heard about Sublime. Besides, Xcode is a native IDE on OSX that officially supported by Apple.

Comment: Yes, but not version 9.  well, good luck anyway. 